# Novel about a boy who defends underground creatures, ends up giving them his eye

Tags: story-identification

A long time ago I read a book about a boy who I think lived like somewhere near the woods. He was trying to help underground creatures defend their home against lumberjacks and in the end of the book the boy gives one of the creatures one of his eyes.

- I remember the cover of the book had stitched eye.
- It might have been a children's book but I'm not certain.

Comment: How long is a "long time ago", do you remember anything about the boy (how old, his name). Were there any other characters? How did he give them his eye??

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/214189/ya-book-about-blind-creatures-that-live-underground-and-take-kids-eyes (which is newer but has an OP-provided answer)

Answer (score 5):

[The Beasties](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0141306394) by William Sleator. Cover is a stitched eye.

Amazon description:

> At first Doug doesn't believe the rumors about bloodthirsty creatures who are said to have left a trail of amputated victims across the northern woods. Then, he and his younger sister find signs of a mysterious presence in the land behind their home. They are about to meet the Beasties, a "family" of beings with war on their minds--war against the human race! Acclaimed science fiction/fantasy author William Sleator has created a fast-paced treat just right for middle-grade Goosebumps fans.

[image]